# How to pick different points in UFT using VB Script

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I' m  doing automation of our software (made in core java) in which I have to left click on several(say 5 left clicks on different points) points on any image.
Every left click should pick different X and Y values, but currently UFT picks same points i.e. first point is applied to all.
Manually it is working fine but in automation it is not. We are using VBscript.

This is the code

```
JavaWindow("label:=Galaxy 4D.*").JavaInternalFrame("text:=Digitize Image").JavaObject("tagname:=JScrollPane","toolkit class:=javax.swing.JScrollPane").Click 201,328,"LEFT"
wait 15

JavaWindow("label:=Galaxy 4D.*").JavaInternalFrame("text:=Digitize Image").JavaObject("tagname:=JScrollPane","toolkit class:=javax.swing.JScrollPane").Click 211,340,"LEFT"
wait 15
JavaWindow("label:=Galaxy 4D.*").JavaInternalFrame("text:=Digitize Image").JavaObject("tagname:=JScrollPane","toolkit class:=javax.swing.JScrollPane").Click 227,351,"LEFT"
wait 15
JavaWindow("label:=Galaxy 4D.*").JavaInternalFrame("text:=Digitize Image").JavaObject("tagname:=JScrollPane","toolkit class:=javax.swing.JScrollPane").Click 231,359,"LEFT"
wait 15
JavaWindow("label:=Galaxy 4D.*").JavaInternalFrame("text:=Digitize Image").JavaObject("tagname:=JScrollPane","toolkit class:=javax.swing.JScrollPane").Click 237,365,"LEFT"
wait 15
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken the coordinates you supply to the `Click` method should be relative to the `JavaObject` in question. Could it be that you're giving coordinates relative to the screen or application and thus are out of the `JavaObject`'s rectangle?